# log4net Exception don't show class location

Tags: c#, log4net

I'm using log for net to log exception in a database. The behavior of the logging is fine, but the inner exception has the message like:

> at ...... message details ..... at
>   C:/User/projects/projectX/classXPTO.cs:line 123

Unfortunately this exception will be monitored by a third party company, and I need to hide the class location:

> C:/User/projects/projectX/classXPTO.cs

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal behaviour while running in Debug.

You have the .pdb files with the running application.
The runtime looks for them when it generates a stack trace to give you as much info as possible.

If you deploy without the .pdb files, it will not show the file location.
You can also run in Release mode;

When deploying a Release build, the PDB files are omitted (unless you specify otherwise)

Comment: Thank you for your answer @alex, but I don't have PDB files. 
This project is a ASP.NET MVC  application, and I published it in release mode. 

Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: Actually I had pdb files in a webservice project, and my erros where coming from there. Thank you!